# Difficulty in understanding the implementation of graphs using Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, struct, graph, singly-linked-list

I am reading a book on `Algorithms` which has following code. I am having difficulty in understanding some lines here.

I have shown `my doubt lines` in the following code as `DOUBT LINE 1` and `DOUBT LINE 2`.
I have also commented a line as `REFERENCE` where I am `having difficulty` to comprehend.
Please elaborate about the `DOUBT LINE 1` and `DOUBT LINE 2`.

```
#define MAXV        100     /* maximum number of vertices */
#define NULL        0       /* null pointer */

/*  DFS edge types      */

#define TREE        0       /* tree edge */
#define BACK        1       /* back edge */
#define CROSS       2       /* cross edge */
#define FORWARD     3       /* forward edge */

typedef struct edgenode {
    int y;              /* adjancency info */
    int weight;         /* edge weight, if any */
    struct edgenode *next;      /* next edge in list */
} edgenode;

typedef struct {
    edgenode *edges[MAXV+1];    /* adjacency info */       //REFERENCE 
    int degree[MAXV+1];     /* outdegree of each vertex */
    int nvertices;          /* number of vertices in the graph */
    int nedges;         /* number of edges in the graph */
    int directed;           /* is the graph directed? */
} graph;
```

it is graph.h   header and there it is  also read and insert functions.

```
read_graph(graph *g, bool directed)
{
    int i;              /* counter */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    int x, y;           /* vertices in edge (x,y) */

    initialize_graph(g, directed);

    scanf("%d %d",&(g->nvertices),&m);

    for (i=1; i<=m; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        insert_edge(g,x,y,directed);
    }
}

insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed)
{
    edgenode *p;            /* temporary pointer */

    p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));   /* allocate storage for edgenode */

    p->weight = NULL;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x]; //DOUBT LINE1

    g->edges[x] = p;        /* insert at head of list */ //DOUBT LINE 2

    g->degree[x] ++;        

    if (directed == FALSE)
        insert_edge(g,y,x,TRUE);
    else
        g->nedges ++;
}
```

Comment: Functions are there in header files? It better not, right?

Answer (score 0):

Each vertex holds a set of edges.  We can regard the set as unordered.  At all times outside of the mutator functions, the pointer `g->edges[i]` points to the first `edgenode` incident on the `i`th vertex, or `NULL` otherwise.  Then, the `next` links in the `edgenode` point to other edges in the set, transitively.

So, to add an edge, you first create a new edge, then assign it's `next` pointer the currently "first" node (DOUBT LINE 1), then assign the `g->edges[i]` pointer the newly created value (DOUBT LINE 2).

Notice that the conditions I said need to exist above are both still satisfied, although the order of the nodes has changed - what was "previously" first is now second, and the new node is first.  That's OK, because we're just storing a set - the order does not matter.

Before (=> traverses a 'next' link):

```
   // edges[i] == <previous> => <other stuff>...
```

After:

```
   //         *             *    These asterisks are above what we set...
   //edges[i] == <new node> => <previous> => <other stuff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Linked list means that `next` is a pointer to the following node.
Example:
`a {some_data,pointer_to_b}`
`b {some_data,pointer_to_c}`
When you want to insert node, you must change `next` pointer of previous node to new node and set new node's `next` pointer to address of following node.
Example:
`a {some_data,pointer_to_d/*what is done at doubt line 1*/}`
`d {some_data,pointer_to_b}` //inserted node what is done at doubt line 2
`b {some_data,pointer_to_c}`

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect so that you understand everything clearly.

The structure of the graph

```
1o-->2o-->#
2o-->3o-->#
3o-->#
4o-->#
5o--.#
```

Here

```
 `1o`: The node 1

 `-->`: It denotes a directed edge.

 `#`: denotes `NULL`
```

Now let's add `2-->4` edge having weight = 5

Step-1: `p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));`

```
p-------->[ ]   ( This is the allocated node)
```

Step-2:   `p->weight = NULL;` // it should be the weight of the edge
          `p->y = y;`

```
| wieght = 5 |
| y = 4      |
| next       |
```

step-3:   `p->next = g->edges[x];` 
g->edges[2] is a pointer to `3o`

```
| wieght = w |
| y = 4      |
| next =------------>3o
```

Now the picture is

```
1o-->2o--->#

p[]--+
     |
     V
2o-->3o--->#
3o-->#
4o-->#
5o--.#
```

step-4: `g->edges[2]=p` 
`g->edges[2]` is basically `2o`

```
1o-->2o--->#
2o-->[] --> 3o--->#
3o-->#
4o-->#
5o-->#
```

Simply

```
1o-->2o--->#
2o-->4o--->3o--->#
3o-->#
4o-->#
5o-->#
```

### Explanation:

Basically here we are maintaining a list where for each node x we put y , z, if there is an edge `x->y` and `x->z`.

If we look into the implementation we will see the nodes are added in front.

For example..if we add `x->y` then the edge list will look like

`x---->y`

Now add z.

`x---->z---->y`

That's all...a friendly tips when you don't get a code get a pencil and paper try to dry run or it or sometimes simply run a debugger.